# Grouping lines by name and determining their proportions using Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, line, sql, virtual-layer, grouping

I have a line layer with hiking trails. The hiking trails are divided into their surfaces. So one hiking trail consist of parts with different surfaces.

I would like to use a virtual layer to group the trails by their name and determine the proportions of the path surfaces (in distance and percentage).

**Example:**
Trail A 20km/100%: 5km/25% Gravel, 10km/50% Asphalt, 5km/25% Path

The very simple SQL-Query for grouping and summing the parts for every trail is:

```sql
SELECT
    name,
    sum(length) AS Length,
    ST_Union(geometry) AS geom
FROM
    Trails
GROUP BY
    name;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not recommend for these cases to use the Virtual Layer (better to put everything in a database).

### step 1

create the first Virtual Layer

```sql
WITH 'toto' AS (
  SELECT
    trail,
    SUM(length) AS length,
    ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry
  FROM
    surface
  GROUP BY
    trail
)
SELECT
  t.trail,
  t.lenTot||'km/100%: '||GROUP_CONCAT(name||'='||t.length||'km/'||t.yyyy||'%') AS list,
  t.geometry
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      t2.trail AS trail,
      t2.surface AS name,
      t1.length AS lenTot,
      t2.length AS length,
      round((CAST(t2.length as REAL) / CAST(t1.length AS REAL)) * 100, 2) AS yyyy,
      t1.geometry AS geometry
    FROM
      toto t1
      LEFT JOIN surface t2 USING (trail)
    GROUP BY
      t2.trail || t2.surface
  ) t
GROUP BY
  1
```

[image]

### output

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Virtual Layer not handling nested queries, I have used CTEs in Virtual Layers plenty of times (WITH ... AS). You could define step 1 as a CTE and refer to that in step 3. I wouldn't recommend having an intermediate static file creation step, that seems to defeat the purpose of virtual layers.

Comment: @she_weeds wow, the CTE works, I didn't know that, thanks.
I have corrected the answer

Comment: Great! Works! I'm using a GeoPackage - isn't it Database enough? :-)

Comment: I'm sorry to ask that, but now I think, it would be better to get results for every surface in a own field (not in a text-list) - could you maybe provide the code also for that?

Comment: @MartinMap ask another question and describe what you want to achieve